# Is user bound to RabbitMQ server or to virtual host?

Tags: rabbitmq

As you know RabbitMQ server can contain several virtual hosts.
Exporting RabbitMQ server settings to JSON and investigating JSON file shows that node with users is server specific - not Vhost specific. But users from Server specific list have Vhost specific access permissions.
Is user bound to RabbitMQ server or to virtual host? In other words, In general, during installation can we ask user to enter single user/password to two Vhosts from single RabbitMQ server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a server has users, and a server has vhosts. users on the server have permissions to vhosts on the server.

you can have a single user with as many or as few permissions as you want. you just need to add the right permissions for that user, on whatever vhost you need.

Comment: Thank you - this match info from "Videla A., Williams J.J.W.- RabbitMQ in Action" : "single user
can be granted permissions across multiple
vhosts."